# clear two textareas with row counters function increment() and function parse()

Tags: javascript

My code is working well except for one issue with my JavaScript function clear() which is not working correctly. I am uncertain how I can get it to work. When a user calls the function clear() from the textbox inputbox then 4 textareas plus one div should be cleared and the row counter reset. The two textareas with row counters (counter1 and counter2) are the once that are creating this problem because three functions are involved there: increment(), parse() and clear().

Simply clearing a textbox with no functions attach to it is rather simple

document.getElementById('inputbox').value = "";

But in my case with two other functions increment() and parse() involved it becomes complicated.

**JavaScript code JavaS plus HTML below**

```js
// first row cursor position in textarea inputbox on page load
function setfocus() {
  var input = document.getElementById('inputbox');
  input.focus();
}

// counts the number of times the user push enter
function increment(a) {
    increment.n = increment.n || 0;
    return ++increment.n; 
}

function parse(e) {
  var key = window.event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { //keycode for enter 

    var input = document.getElementById('inputbox');
    var output = eval(input.value);

    var cc = increment();
    document.getElementById("count1").value += '\n' + eval(cc + 1);
    document.getElementById("count2").value += cc + '\n';

    var out = document.getElementById("outputbox").value
    if (out == "" || out.length == 0 || out == null) {
      document.getElementById("outputbox").value += output;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("outputbox").value += '\n' + output;
    }
  }
}

// clears the input and output boxes
function clear() {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('count1').value = "1";
  document.getElementById('count2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('inputbox').value = "";
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('outputbox').value = "";
};

// an array with random numbers between -1 and 1
function rand(n) {
  x = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  }
  console.log("x = " + x);
  return x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaS.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    .bb {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #count1 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 20px;
      height: 350px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #inputbox {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      height: 350px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #count2 {
      background-color: pink;
      width: 20px;
      height: 350px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #outputbox {
      background-color: pink;
      width: 500px;
      height: 350px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #mydiv {
      background-color: lightgrey;
      width: 1066px;
      height: 380px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="bb" style="background-color: lightblue; display: inline-block;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">User defined JavaScript function input</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea id="count1" disabled>1 </textarea> </td>
      <td><textarea id="inputbox" onkeypress="parse(event, this)"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="bb" style="background-color: pink; display: inline-block;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Command output</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea id="count2" disabled></textarea> </td>
      <td><textarea id="outputbox"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="bb" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Plot or help output </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div id="mydiv"> </div>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script> setfocus(); </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit it to a minimal necessary code.

Comment: I have deleted the non relevant JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem myself.

```js
function parse(e) {
  var key = window.event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { //keycode for enter 

    var input = document.getElementById('inputbox');
    var output = eval(input.value);

    var cc = increment();
    console.log("cc = " + cc);
    var out = document.getElementById("outputbox").value ;
    
    if (out == "" || out.length == 0 || out == null) {
      document.getElementById("count1").value += eval(cc + 1) + '\n';
      document.getElementById("count2").value = eval(cc);
      document.getElementById("outputbox").value += output;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("count1").value += eval(cc + 1) + '\n';
      document.getElementById("count2").value += '\n' + eval(cc);
      document.getElementById("outputbox").value += '\n' + output;
    }
  }
  if (cc == 0) { document.getElementById("count2").value = "" };
}

// clears the input and output boxes
function clear() {
  event.preventDefault();
  increment.n = -1;
  document.getElementById('count1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('count2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('inputbox').value = "";
  document.getElementById('outputbox').value = "";
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "";
  return "";
};
```